# Trying to return a record from from a dataframe sing a reference dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (`DeptTemplate`) the .head() of which looks like:

```
       Name     Status  Status change date   Product
0       Bob    CURRENT                 NaN   Pencils
1     Steve    CURRENT                 NaN      Pens
2   Heather NEW JOINER          02/08/2018     Paper
3     Lizzy NEW JOINER          06/02/2018      Pens
4     Ralph       LEFT                 NaN     Paper
```

I am trying to identify and return all the information for records that have a non 'CURRENT' Status and also no Status change date.

The code below explains my methodology:

```
 def checkStatusChangeDate(DeptTemplate,filename,filepath, referencePeriodStartDate, referencePeriodEndDate,writer):
        #This code checks if a status is not current that there is a status change date attached

        test = DeptTemplate[DeptTemplate.Status != "CURRENT"]

        pd.to_datetime(test['Status change date'])

        test['Status change date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')   

        statusError = test['Status change date'] == 'NaT'

        finalError = DeptTemplate.loc[statusError['Status change date']]
```

I first of all identify any records that are not 'CURRENT'.  I then identify from this subset any records that do not have a status change date.  I end up with `statusError` data frame that looks like:

```
4    False
```

where the only record which does not have a CURRENT status and no Status change date is for Ralph.

The bit that I get stuck on is then trying to return Ralphs entire record by then referencing the `statusError` dataframe against the original `DeptTemplate`.

I am trying to use:

either:

```
finalError = DeptTemplate.loc[statusError['Status change date']]
```

or

```
finalError = DeptTemplate[statusError['Status change date']]
```

but can't get the whole record to return in the `finalError` dataframe

(so I end up with a `finalError` dataframe that looks like:

```
       Name     Status  Status change date   Product
4     Ralph       LEFT                 NaN     Paper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, but you are trying to slice your original `DataFrame` using a a slice of a different `DataFrame` - that won't work because they are not the same thing.

Step 1: Set boolean masks

```
not_current = df['STATUS'] != 'CURRENT'

no_date_change = df['Status change date'].isnull()
```

Step 2: Use masks

```
df[not_current & no_date_change]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly: You want to find one Record which does not contain a change date and no CURRENT status and then want to return all aother records to for this. So if there are other entries for Ralph for example you want to get them as well.

My solution for this would be:

```
import pandas as pd 


data = {"Name":["Bob","Steve","Heather","Lizzy","Ralph","Ralph","Ralph"],
    "Status":["CURRENT","CURRENT","NEW JOINER","NEW JOINER","LEFT","CURRENT","CURRENT"],
    "Status change date": ["","","02/08/2018","06/02/2018","","06/02/2018","06/02/2018"],
    "Product":["Pencils","Pens","Paper","Pens","Paper","Pencils","Pens"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["Status change date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Status change date"])

df.head()
      Name      Status Status change date  Product
0      Bob     CURRENT                NaT  Pencils
1    Steve     CURRENT                NaT     Pens
2  Heather  NEW JOINER         2018-02-08    Paper
3    Lizzy  NEW JOINER         2018-06-02     Pens
4    Ralph        LEFT                NaT    Paper
5    Ralph     CURRENT         2018-06-02  Pencils
6    Ralph     CURRENT         2018-06-02     Pens
```

get all entries that are contain no CURRENT status and no status change date:

```
finalError = df[(df["Status"]!="CURRENT") & (df["Status change date"].isnull())]

finalError.head()

    Name Status Status change date Product
4  Ralph   LEFT                NaT   Paper
```

Now check for the names in the old dataframe to get all the records from Ralph.

```
df[df["Name"]==finalError["Name"].any()]

    Name   Status Status change date  Product
4  Ralph     LEFT                NaT    Paper
5  Ralph  CURRENT         2018-06-02  Pencils
6  Ralph  CURRENT         2018-06-02     Pens
```